# Temp files s3 slow down with beam (throtteling)

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm trying to use apache beam with Flink at AWS KDA. This pipeline reads some data from kinesis and after a simple transformation, it tries to group the results into one shard using this strategy:

```
.apply("Creating micro-batches", Window.<XXX>into(new GlobalWindows())
                            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(windowSizePanes),
                                            AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().alignedTo(windowSizeSeconds))))
                            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(60), Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY)
                            .discardingFiredPanes()
                    );
```

The problem is, I'm facing a lot of s3 slow down exceptions and it just have 100 temp files at the same moment when the error occurs:

```
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsynchronousException: Caught exception while processing timer.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$StreamTaskAsyncExceptionHandler.handleAsyncException(StreamTask.java:1319)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.handleAsyncException(StreamTask.java:1295)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1434)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$deferCallbackToMailbox$16(StreamTask.java:1423)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:344)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:681)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:636)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:620)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:784)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: TimerException{org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator}
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.WindowDoFnOperator.fireTimer(WindowDoFnOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.fireTimerInternal(DoFnOperator.java:1001)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.onProcessingTime(DoFnOperator.java:995)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimerServiceImpl.onProcessingTime(InternalTimerServiceImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1432)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.emit(DoFnOperator.java:1171)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.output(DoFnOperator.java:1121)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:99)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1058)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:445)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:130)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1061)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:932)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:793)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:137)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$ToGroupByKeyResult.flatMap(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:1416)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$ToGroupByKeyResult.flatMap(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:1388)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.emit(DoFnOperator.java:1171)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.output(DoFnOperator.java:1121)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:99)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1058)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:445)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:130)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1061)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:932)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:793)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:137)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.WindowDoFnOperator.fireTimer(WindowDoFnOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.fireTimerInternal(DoFnOperator.java:1001)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.onProcessingTime(DoFnOperator.java:995)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimerServiceImpl.onProcessingTime(InternalTimerServiceImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1432)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$deferCallbackToMailbox$16(StreamTask.java:1423)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:344)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:681)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:636)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:620)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:784)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: 5HFF75416KXD5RMN; S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.processElement(DoFnOperator.java:645)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: 5HFF75416KXD5RMN; S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3WritableByteChannel.<init>(S3WritableByteChannel.java:100)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.create(S3FileSystem.java:416)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.create(S3FileSystem.java:90)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.create(FileSystems.java:243)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.open(FileBasedSink.java:962)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:933)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: 5HFF75416KXD5RMN; S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 2RZe+jaSpkhPEVt1VgPoZ/CsE51SwMQJA4BWVR4qyXB7TazD43NdsEj19AnKKleswZSyo964R0A=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1862)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1415)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1154)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:811)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:779)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:753)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:713)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:695)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:559)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:539)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5437)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5384)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:3715)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3WritableByteChannel.<init>(S3WritableByteChannel.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.create(S3FileSystem.java:416)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.create(S3FileSystem.java:90)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.create(FileSystems.java:243)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.open(FileBasedSink.java:962)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:933)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.processElement(DoFnOperator.java:645)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$ToGroupByKeyResult.flatMap(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:1416)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators$ToGroupByKeyResult.flatMap(FlinkStreamingTransformTranslators.java:1388)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.emit(DoFnOperator.java:1171)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator$BufferedOutputManager.output(DoFnOperator.java:1121)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:99)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1058)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:445)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:130)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1061)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:932)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:793)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn.java:137)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetNewDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.WindowDoFnOperator.fireTimer(WindowDoFnOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.fireTimerInternal(DoFnOperator.java:1001)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.DoFnOperator.onProcessingTime(DoFnOperator.java:995)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimerServiceImpl.onProcessingTime(InternalTimerServiceImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1432)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$deferCallbackToMailbox$16(StreamTask.java:1423)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:344)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:681)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:636)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:620)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:784)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of error information, it is simply an error of S3 current limit.

This error occurs when there are too many requests for the same bucket at the same time. You may consult S3 customer service for the issue of S3 current limit

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ChangLi, I contacted the AWS support to check the limits and we are using the defaults. The curious part only occurs after 12h of processing .. at the end I'm trying to partition my data and instantiate the same amount of writers, then I can split my temp folders prefix using this partitions. At the end, I don't know why it's writing so much, I tried to limit the bundle size but it doesn't change this behavior.

Comment: After chatting with AWS, I could conclude it was a miss-understand about how prefix at s3 and the scalability there works (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/). The problem was generated by another prefix facing miss-use, and as the entire bucket was partitioned based on bucket name, those prefixes with slow down was affecting my temp folder prefix. The s3 access logs were primordial to analyse that behavior.

At the end, it really wasn't something regarding with beam.